# sqlite is required for merb?

Tags: merb

I have a question regarding merb dependency with sqlite. I am going to install merb on my m/c and I don't have sqlite installed on my m/c . I tried this command "gem install merb" and saw following error. If there any way to install merb with mysql please tell me.

> Building native extensions.  This
>   could take a while... ERROR:  Error
>   installing merb:  ERROR: Failed to
>   build gem native extension.
>
> /usr/bin/ruby1.8 extconf.rb checking
>   for sqlite3.h... no
>   *** extconf.rb failed *** Could not create Makefile due to some reason,
>   probably lack of necessary libraries
>   and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log
>   file for more details.  You may need
>   configuration options.
>
> Provided configuration options:
>     --with-opt-dir  --without-opt-dir
>     --with-opt-include
>     --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
>     --with-opt-lib
>     --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
>     --with-make-prog    --without-make-prog
>     --srcdir=.  --curdir
>     --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby1.8
>     --with-sqlite3-dir
>     --without-sqlite3-dir
>     --with-sqlite3-include
>     --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
>     --with-sqlite3-lib
>     --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/do_sqlite3-0.10.2
>   for inspection. Results logged to
>   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/do_sqlite3-0.10.2/ext/do_sqlite3/gem_make.out

Answer (score 0):

haven't ever used merb, but it is probably using sqlite as a default for databases, which is why its a framework dependency. if you are on ubuntu, try

```
sudo apt-get install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev libsqlite3-ruby
sudo gem install sqlite3-ruby
```

if you are on another distro or another os, google for how to install the dev version of sqlite, then install the gem (second line)

rails has the same dependency, if you google for the error and your os, you will probably get about a billion results telling you what to get.

Comment: @mayank if that answer was useful please, upvote and validate it.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to choose an ORM for your project, which merb does not have built-in. The most popular choice is [DataMapper](http://datamapper.org), which has abstractions that will let you use mysql without problems. Check the DataMapper docs for setup.

You can even use a database.yml file identical to rails if you'd like; DM accepts the same values.